# Switching to Immutable.js in Redux. What is the performance hit and what is the effect on the components' syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am considering moving my reducers from plain JS to [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).
It will take a few days to understand immutable.js api and do the refactor with the tests and I want to give some thought to whether this transition is necessary. My motivation is the fact I am currently duplicating the state on every change:

```
  let newState = {...state};
```

This is expensive and leads me to forget cloning deep objects from time to time.

Googling the issue for the last days I still don't understand whether moving my reducers to immutable.js will result in a performance hit and whether I would need to go through my components and containers and use state.toJS() on each one.

What is the performance hit on moving to **immutable.js**? especially when I use [undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo) and keep multiple steps. Will I have to use .toJS() every time I need data for my components/containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer about performance: it depends. To quote Dan Abramov [here](https://github.com/reactiflux/q-and-a/blob/master/dan-abramov_react-core.md),

> In short: create a sample app that imitates the kinda of data size and change speed you expect in your app, and profile it. No other way to tell if dropping Immutable is going to work for you.

One of the major benefits to using a library like immutable is as you mentioned, it prevents you from forgetting to clone deep objects from time to time, which can lead to really nasty bugs that are hard to track down. Likewise, undo can be much easier with immutable if you keep track of previous states, whereas they are much much more involved without an immutable library since you basically have to deep clone state before creating new state.

I think it's worth a try, but you can always move a few reducers at a time to using immutable instead of migrating your entire app. That way you can profile performance impacts and see if it's worth it to migrate the entire app.

Comment: In addition to the answer, one more quote from Dan Abramov:

Pros of using Immutable with Redux:

- You can't mutate by mistake;
- Way faster performance and better memory consumption with large arrays and objects.

Cons of using Immutable with Redux:

- New API to learn for your team;
- Increased bundle size;
- Slightly trickier to debug.

The tradeoff is up to you!

Answer (score 2):

My own personal opinion is that use of Immutable.js is mostly overrated for most situations.  I wrote an extended comment on Reddit describing my concerns, at ([Dan Abramov: Redux is not an architecture or design pattern, it is just a library](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4rcqpx/dan_abramov_redux_is_not_an_architecture_or/d51g4k4?context=3)).  I'll paste the TL;DR: here:

> Overall, my impression is that the performance benefits are overrated, it's too easy to make mistakes in usage that are actually a net performance negative, and you either have to go all-in on the API everywhere in your codebase or be very sure you know when you're using Immutable types vs plain JS and do conversions all over the place.

So yes, you generally either have to use `toJS()`, or explicitly call `state.getIn()` to extract pieces of data.

My React/Redux links list has a section on React performance, which includes several articles regarding Immutable.js performance (including some pitfalls, like overuse of `toJS()`) : [react-redux-links](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#immutable-data).

Comment: You almost never should use `toJS` or its inverse. In my app, the only area where I have had the need to use these is when sending data to `web-workers`. That & perhaps for, sending to / from backend endpoints, you should never use these function. If you are, you are probably not using it properly.